We ran out of draw cards
We were 5 players, we followed the rules, we have 4 exploding kittens and 1 "defuse" card each. Whenever 1 explodes without a defuse card available we put everything back to the discard pile. If there is defuse then we discard the defuse and put back the exploding kitten. We followed the rules but somehow we ran out of draw file. My dad somehow got 3 diffuse cards before we ran out. How do we play it when we ran out? How many exploding kitten and defuse cards should we put back in since there is only two players left?

You didn't follow the rules. If you had, then 4 players would have drawn exploding kittens and the 5th player would have won.

The only time it's possible for the draw pile to be empty is when the very last card was the last exploding kitten, which would be the end of the game. Otherwise mistakes were being made with putting defused kittens into discard or someone was cheating.

If you follow the rules, then when there are two players left there will be exactly 1 exploding kitten card left in the draw pile. Keep playing until one player draws the exploding kitten. That player loses the game
From the rules:

Insert enough Exploding Kittens back into the deck so that there is 1
fewer than the number of people playing.

and

Eventually, every player will explode except for one, who wins the
game! You won’t ever run out of cards in the Draw Pile because you
inserted enough Exploding Kittens to kill all but 1 player.

If you're still having trouble, keep this in mind:

When you die, put the kitten that killed you face up in front of you
so that everyone can see that you’re dead, and put the rest of your
cards face down in front of you.

The three players that are out will each have a face up exploding kitten in front of them. Since you started with four exploding kittens, you know that there is still exactly 1 in the draw pile. Remember that any time an exploding kitten is drawn, either a player "dies" or that kitten is put back in to the deck.
